# Not getting HTTP referrer on HTTPS site

Tags: php, https, referrer

I'm using NGINX with an HTTPS site.

My PHP script stores the HTTP referrer value:

```
<?php
echo "Ref = ".$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
?>
```

This works fine for Facebook, but for Google, the referrer is blank. The way I test this is using Google drive and Gmail, having the HTTPS:// link in an email or document, then clicking it to open.

I thought for HTTPS to HTTPS, the referrer was passed.

So how would I see sites like Google, etc?

Thanks

Comment: FYI: `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]` can't be relied on.

Comment: Some websites chose to implement norefferer option to prevent information leak. For example, if someone clicks on a link that's in google doc, they don't want server that's receiving the request to get link to the doc that it came from. Generally speaking, you should not use `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]` for anything except maybe some internal flow tracking.

Comment: OK, so is there any way to see which website referred the user on?